# How to fix "can only concatenate str (not "float") to str" when working with slope, intercept?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm just a beginner and I'm writing a code to analyze some data and for that I need to analyze the slope of some graphs. I have code that was used before to analyze something similar and  want to modify it. I need to analyze when slope is more that 0 and then it should register that as a beginning and when stop when slope is negative. But I'm getting an error.

```
 data = pd.read_csv(file, names=['Date', 'Potential, V', 'CO2', 'RH',
                                 'Pressure, mmHg', 'Tempereture, C'])                                          
 dateindex = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  
    List = ['Date', 'Potential, V', 'CO2', 'RH', 'Pressure, mmHg', 'Tempereture, C']

for CH in List:
    for i in range(6, len(dateindex)):
        slope[i], intercept= np.polyfit(range(len(dateindex))[i - 6:i],data[CH][i - 6:i],1)
        if slope[i - 1] < 0 and slope[i] > 0:
            start = i
            R0 = np.mean(data[CH][i - 2:i - 1])

        if slope[i - 1] > 0 and slope[i] < 0:
            end = i
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/ADA (Automatic Data Analysis)/read2.py", line 62, in <module>
    slope[i], intercept= np.polyfit(range(len_dateindex)[i - 6:i],data[CH][i - 6:i],1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in polyfit
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\ADA (Automatic Data Analysis)\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 593, in polyfit
    y = NX.asarray(y) + 0.0

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Comment: Try using `astype(np.float)` like so: `slope[i], intercept= np.polyfit(range(len_dateindex)[i - 6:i].astype(np.float),data[CH][i - 6:i].astype(np.float),1)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
This appears to be a simple type conversion problem -- but we can only guess, since you failed to include the values causing the error.

Comment: Exactly - what's CH, List, data, len_dateindex and dateindex?

Comment: data-data frame   dataindex-series  List - list  CH - string

Comment: `polyfit` expects all the inputs to be numeric arrays.  At least one of the columns of `data` is object dtype with string elements.  Either skip those columns, or do something to convert them (dates?) to numbers.